# Media query breakpoints off by 17px

Tags: css, wordpress

I've been coding websites using media queries for years but I'm baffled by this new behavior.

My breakpoint is `@media only screen and (max-width : 1200px)` but it doesn't respond until max-width is 1183px.

This is happening for all breakpoints, off by 17px. It's not the scrollbar, it's not a plugin or another script and it's happening on multiple computers. Page zoom is set to 100% and I have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` in my header.

This is not a production site so I can't post access but if someone has some idea as to why this might be happening, I would appreciate it!

Comment: I'm having this same issue and I'm glad you mentioned the scrollbar. The scrollbar is exactly 17px. It seems that Chrome's (and I think Firefox's) inspection tool subtracts the scrollbar's width from the Body and screen size measurements, while media queries don't. If you add `overflow: hidden` to the `body` tag, the query will trigger right where it's supposed to (which isn't a solution of course, but it proves that the scrollbar is the culprit).